# Can you use a Publisher directly as an @ObjectBinding property in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI, can you use an instance of a `Publisher` directly as an `@ObjectBinding` property or do you have to wrap it in a class that implements `BindableObject`?

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
let view = ContentView(data:subject)

struct ContentView : View {
  @ObjectBinding var data:AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
}

// When I want to refresh the view, I can just call: 
subject.send(())
```

This doesn't compile for me and just hangs Xcode 11 Beta 2. But should you even be allowed to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your View body use `.onReceive` passing in the publisher like the example below, taken from [Data Flow Through SwiftUI - WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/) @ 21:23. Inside the closure you update an @State var, which in turn is referenced somewhere else in the body which causes body to be called when it is changed.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can implement a `BindableObject` wich takes a publisher as initializer parameter.

And extend `Publisher` with a convenience function to create this `BindableObject`.

```swift
class BindableObjectPublisher<PublisherType: Publisher>: BindableObject where PublisherType.Failure == Never {

    typealias Data = PublisherType.Output

    var didChange: PublisherType
    var data: Data?

    init(didChange: PublisherType) {
        self.didChange = didChange
        _ = didChange.sink { (value) in
            self.data = value
        }
    }
}

extension Publisher where Failure == Never {
    func bindableObject() -> BindableObjectPublisher<Self> {
        return BindableObjectPublisher(didChange: self)
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var binding = Publishers.Just("test").bindableObject()

    var body: some View {
        Text(binding.data ?? "Empty")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however that's exactly the scenario I was hoping to avoid when I referred to wrapping a `Publisher` in a class. I was hoping there was some protocol or existing API that I had overlooked.

Comment: `BindableObject`s musst be a class. So this is not to avoid.